# insert link into php

Tags: php, html

I am having trouble putting this link into my php code.  I always get messed up on the quotes, and mixing html and php.

```
$message = "Please verify your account.  Please click on the following link to verify your      account: <a href='confirm.php?code=$code'> here</a>. If you should have any problems activating your account, please e-mail us at contact@mywebsite.com";
```

Comment: @Truth the problem is a misuse of double quotes when defining the variable

Comment: @Tom I see no problem with the definition of the variable. Where do you see a double quote misuse?

Comment: @Truth actually, I'm not sure... I totally mixed it up, the use of single/double quotes. The above code is 100% correct and I have no idea what the problem is either..

Comment: it will output <a href="confirm.php?code=codeNumber">  instead of a link.  it must be with the headers, i think.

Comment: @droidus - Update your question, and then have a look at my answer

Answer (score 3):

wrap it in single quotes

`$message = 'Please verify your account.  Please click on the following link to verify your      account: <a href="confirm.php?code=' . $code . '"> here</a>. If you should have any problems activating your account, please e-mail us at contact@mywebsite.com';`

If you wrap it in single quotes you can use double quotes and vice versa. If you need single quotes and it is wrapped with single quotes, escape it using `\` you can't use variables in single quotes with out concat-ing them though

Comment: when i do that, i get an error with: "confirm.php?code=$code"

Comment: The above code won't work since you've used single-quotes for the anchors attribute. Change them to double-quotes

Comment: i have this, but it still doesn't like it.  it spits out the link. <a href="confirm.php?code=' . $code . '">  I am using this to send an e-mail.  i use this: $body = "Hello, $uname! \n$message";
  $headers = 'From: ' .' <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;

Comment: @droidus You have to add HTML headers to the email in order to get it to correctly output your code

Answer (score 0):

```
$message = 'We endeavor you to verify your account.  Please click on the following link to verify your account: <a href="confirm.php?code=' . $code . '">Verification link</a>. If you should have any problems activating your account, please e-mail us at <a href="mailto:contact@mywebsite.com">our customer support e-mail address.</a> Thank you.';
```